# UnsatisfiedLinkError on 64-bit Android when loading 32-bit JNI library (on LG Flex2)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, 32bit-64bit, native-code

I've written an Android application calling into a 32-bit JNI library.
On a Galaxy Note 4 (32-bit, Snapdragon 805) everything works as expected, on a LG Flex2 (64-bit, Snapdragon 810) the app only works when passing the parameter "--abi armeabi-v7a" to ADB (obviously).

However, when installing the jar-file manually, Android assumes it is a 64-bit application, which results in the UnsatisfiedLinkError listed below.

This is what I've checked/tried:
 - There are no 64-bit libraries present in the whole APK
 - There is only a single arch-specific directory inside the APK (lib/armeabi-v7a)
 - The native libraries are built with "LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32"

Any idea why Android insists on running this application in 64-bit mode?
From what I've read, Android should automatically detect legacy 32-bit applications during installation when encountering only 32-bit native shared libraries.

Thank you in advance, Clemens

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/at.ac.ait.modentity-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/at.ac.ait.modentity-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "liblept.so"
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
```

PS: Please no comments suggesting to deploy 64-bit libs, I would like the app executed in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a dependency that was pulling in native libraries (realm, librealm-jni.so) for many different architectures.

So the installer detected this single 64-bit shared library and decided the application is 64-bit aware/safe.